# How do use ConcurrencyHashmap another class or main method?

Tags: java, netty

```
public class keyClientHandler extends ChannelInboundHandlerAdapter{

public static ConcurrentHashMap<String, String> keyTable = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();

String information;
String hashMapKey; 
String hashMapValue; 

@Override
public void channelRead(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, Object msg) throws Exception {

    // do something

    keyTable.put(hashMapKey, hashMapValue);

    System.out.println(keyTable.size()); //size = 268
}

public static ConcurrentHashMap<String,String> getKeyTable() {

    return keyTable;
}
```

Another class use:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    ConcurrentHashMap<String, String> map = keyClientHandler.getKeyTable();

    System.out.println(map.size()); //size=0

}
```

When i try to use stuffed concurrentMap on another class or in the main method, it returns empty.
How can i use Concurentmap from another classes?

Comment: Seems to work fine. You're getting the reference and it's not null. It's empty, but that just means that nothing has put data in there yet. This is very basic stuff. There's also nothing CHM specific about this question.

Comment: It seems you are running your program in two different VMs

Comment: You have to be using the same map in the same JVM. Note: if you use a distributed map like Chronicle Map, this can be shared across multiple JVMs.

Comment: I think he has only one VM, but `keyClientHandler.getKeyTable();` is a static method (with his poorly named class resembling a variable name) accessing a (public) static CHM. None of the channel reading is ever happening, and I suspect he's in over his head.

Comment: I agree with @Kayaman. Don't think he meant different VM's.

Answer (score 0):

### How we interpreted your problem?

```
    public static ConcurrentHashMap<String, String> keyTable = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();
```

static `concurrentHashMap` has been defined in `class KeyClientHandler`. You intended to retrieve the map object and print the size of the map from `main method` of **another** class. Now as you said, your program runs and it prints 0 as the output. This means you are alright in terms of accessing the map. You should have got *compilation errors*, if your concurrentHashMap was not accessible from the said main method of another class.

### What can be a possible way to demonstrate that this better?

I think the following improvements are required. Firstly, you don't need to use static map or static methods here. We can demonstrate this without static'ness as well. Try running this example which is a slight modification of your code.

```
import java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap;

class ChannelHandlerContext {
    // some class
}

class KeyClientHandler{
    public ConcurrentHashMap<String, String> keyTable = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();

    String information;
    String hashMapKey; 
    String hashMapValue; 

    KeyClientHandler() {

    }

    public void setKeyValue(String key, String value){
        hashMapKey = key;
        hashMapValue = value;   
    }

    public  void channelRead(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, Object msg) throws Exception {
        // do something
        keyTable.put(hashMapKey, hashMapValue);
        System.out.println(keyTable.size()); //size = 268
    }

    public ConcurrentHashMap<String,String> getKeyTable() {
       return keyTable;
    }
}

public class TestConcurrentHashMap {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        KeyClientHandler keyClientHandler = new KeyClientHandler();
        keyClientHandler.setKeyValue("apples", "fruit");
        ConcurrentHashMap<String, String> map = keyClientHandler.getKeyTable();
        try {
            keyClientHandler.channelRead(null, null); // not the best thing
            System.out.println(map.size()); //size=1
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Output:
1

Comment: First thank you for your answer but my issue is different.

I  need'nt to put map another class . I have to stuffed concurrentmap in channelRead method and i want to use this map values in another class.

Comment: @AtakanCoşar And from where will you call channelRead method. In the example you shared, I don't see any calls. If it were called and you had stuffed the hashMap then the result will show up in the main method.

Answer (score 0):

My project is socket programming. I use Netty Framework. I send TCP client and received message send other client.

Server :

```
public class KeyClient {

static final String HOST = System.getProperty("host", "...");
static final int PORT = Integer.parseInt(System.getProperty("port", "..."));

public static void keyClientStart() throws InterruptedException {

    EventLoopGroup group = new NioEventLoopGroup();
    try {
        Bootstrap bootstrap = new Bootstrap();
        bootstrap.group(group)
                 .channel(NioSocketChannel.class)
                 .option(ChannelOption.TCP_NODELAY, true)
                 .handler(new keyClientInitializer());

        ChannelFuture future = bootstrap.connect(HOST, PORT).sync();
        future.channel().closeFuture().sync();
    } finally {
        group.shutdownGracefully();
    }

}
}
```

KeyClientInitializer :

```
public class keyClientInitializer extends ChannelInitializer<SocketChannel> {

@Override
protected void initChannel(SocketChannel ch) throws Exception {

    ChannelPipeline pipeline = ch.pipeline();

    pipeline.addLast(new LoggingHandler(LogLevel.INFO));

    pipeline.addLast(new FixedLengthFrameDecoder(32));

    pipeline.addLast(new keyClientHandler());
}
}
```

KeyClientHandler :

```
public class keyClientHandler extends ChannelInboundHandlerAdapter{

public static ConcurrentHashMap<String, String> keyTable = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();

String information;
String hashMapKey; 
String hashMapValue; 

@Override
public void channelRead(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, Object msg) throws Exception {

    ByteBuf buffer = (ByteBuf) msg;

    byte[] receivedKey = byteBufToByteArray(buffer);

    information = DatatypeConverter.printHexBinary(receivedKey);

    // do something
    // ...

    keyTable.put(hashMapKey, hashMapValue); //map has elements



}

@Override
public void exceptionCaught(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, Throwable cause) throws Exception {
    cause.printStackTrace();
}

public static ConcurrentHashMap<String,String> getKeyTable() {
       return keyTable;
 }

private byte[] byteBufToByteArray(ByteBuf buffer) {

    byte[] receivedKey;
    int offset;
    int length = buffer.readableBytes();

    if (buffer.hasArray()) {
        receivedKey = buffer.array();
        offset = buffer.arrayOffset();
    } else {
        receivedKey = new byte[length];
        buffer.getBytes(buffer.readerIndex(), receivedKey);
        offset = 0;
    }

    return receivedKey;
}

}
```

Test class:

```
public class AppMain {

public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {

    KeyClient.keyClientStart();

    ConcurrentHashMap<String, String> map = keyClientHandler.getKeyTable(); // is empty

}
```

When i add 'System.out.println(keyTable);' in keyClientHandler, i see map values.
[Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yIUs0.png)

Comment: When you make this call, how do you know if data has been received by your clientHandler.

Comment: When i add 'System.out.println(keyTable);' in keyClientHandler, i see map values.

Comment: Try to print using:      for (String key: keyTable.keySet()){

            
            System.out.println(key + "  " + keyTable.get(key));  


}

Comment: OUTPUT:
E201:E201:FF0246DA2AFBE35C0453A0000000000000000
E201:E201:FF00D25BE25083AE54E6D0000000000000000
E201:E201:EA15C0000000000000000D3CFC66883B10135
E201:E201:FF0164FF3216398F416A20000000000000000

Comment: i recevied keys in keyClientHandler but i don't use keys another class. @DROY

Comment: I ran your program and saw that your channelRead is not getting called. Here is my output: 
         +-------------------------------------------------+
         |  0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9  a  b  c  d  e  f |
+--------+-------------------------------------------------+----------------+
|00000000| 53 65 72 76 65 72 20 6d 65 73 73 61 67 65 0a    |Server message. |
+--------+-------------------------------------------------+----------------+
INFO: [id: 0xd65f6cb7, L:/127.0.0.1:51684 ! R:localhost/127.0.0.1:9890] INACTIVE
MAP SIZE: 0

Comment: Your result is normal because i hide server address and port. i added output screen. you can see @DROY

Comment: In your case can you check if channelRead is called.

Answer (score 0):

On my case it's OK to hold the CHM object on other class, you can check:

- Is the `System.out.println(keyTable.size());` called after `channelRead(...)` ?   you print the key on which class? if the next channel handler, should you call `ctx.fireChannelRead(msg);` ?
- Other way you can print the CHM `hashCode()`, if they are the same, that means same object.